# How I can disable 'basic authentication' access methodology on firefox 3.6?

Tags: security, proxy, authentication, firefox-3.6

I want to disable in Firefox 3.6.12 the basic authentication access schema.

Is there a way to disable this kind of basically insecure authentication schema and allow only non plain/text authentication schema ?

Where i work, when I try to authenticate on the HTTP proxy,  Firefox try to use a more secure authentication schema, but for some reason it's fail, after this try, it's use basic authentication.

Because this kind of authentication schema is insecure, is there a way to disable this kind of authentication ?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know about your proxy, Basic Auth isn't always insecure.  Basic Auth + https => Secure.

A quick cruise of the Mozilla/Firefox configuration URL `about:config` didn't show anything promising, sorry.